# "Where are you coming from" is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

I was taught that **where are you going to** is incorrect.

But if I use:

> Where are you coming.

It seems to be ambiguous.

Can I say:

> Where are you coming from.

Please Explain.

Answer (score 1):

> Where are you going to?

is not "incorrect"; it's merely a bit redundant. Your teachers probably want you to say "Where are you going?" for that reason, and you should take their advice in this but only with a grain of salt.

But you can't use the naked "Where are you coming?" You have to indicate the direction with *from*:

> Where are you coming from?

English used to use the adverbs *whither* and *whence* to indicate motion to or from a location:

> Whither are you going? [Whither goest thou?]

meant "Where are you going [to]?" and

> Whence come you? [Whence comest thou?]

meant "Where are you coming from?"

These were handy additions to the vocabulary, but unfortunately they are now obsolete. You can't use them without sounding strange, ironic, or supercilious.

Answer (score 0):

When the word "where" refers to a destination, you usually don't use the preposition "to" as it's redundant.  However, the use of this preposition is not  ungrammatical; many people use it.

Where are you coming from?

The sentence is absolutely grammatical.  When "where" refers to a point of origin, the preposition "from" is required (The Free Dictionary).